# Enviar lista de objetos JSON c#

Tags: c#, json, lista

Bom, seguinte, estou tentando enviar uma lista de objetos através do JSON para uma controller C#, onde contem um objeto **Resposta**, e nesse objeto, contem outro chamado **Campo**.
Porem, na controller, eu recebo apenas o id de **Campo**, e nada de **Resposta**, não consigo visualizar o problema.
Minha array consegue pegar os dados como deveria, só não é passado tudo pra controller.

**JSON**

```
var urlResposta = '@Url.Action("Create", "Resultado")';
var dtoEnvio = new Array();
            $('.resposta').each(function () {
                var obj = {
                        Resposta: {
                            Resp: $(this).find('.perg-resp').first().val()
                        },
                        Campo: { Id: $(this).find('#hidID').first().val() }
                    };
                dtoEnvio.push(obj);
            });
            console.log(dtoEnvio)

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlResposta,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(dtoEnvio),
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
            }
        })
    };
```

**Propriedades classe C#**

```
public class Resposta
    {
        public virtual Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual String Resp { get; set; }
        public virtual Campos Campo { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(List<Resposta> listResposta)
        {
        }
```

**Lista de Resposta**
[image: Lista de resposta]
**DTO**

[image: DTO]

Comment: Coloca o Json que você está mandando, vai ajudar a entender o problema.

Comment: @Ricardo seria isso ? 0: Object
Campo: Object
Id: "1"
__proto__: Object
Resposta: Object
Resp: "a"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
Pois o código do JSON e tal, ta ai em cima.. obrigado !

Comment: Isso, o conteúdo mesmo do Json, edita a pergunta e coloca ele formatado lá. O que você está usando para teste mesmo.

Comment: No controle vc espera Resp, no Json envia Resposta, se não tiver mapeado no mão ele não vai fazer automaticamente, muda o Jason para Resp ou o controle para Resposta, se funcionar me fala q crio uma resposta

Comment: @Ricardo, exatamente isso Ricardo, removi Resposta no json, e funcionou, se quiser criar a resposta, esta funcionando da seguinte maneira:
`$('.resposta').each(function () {
                var obj = {
                        Resp: $(this).find('.perg-resp').first().val(),
                        Campo: { Id: $(this).find('#hidID').first().val() }
                    };
                dtoEnvio.push(obj);
            });`

Comment: Adicionei a resposta, se resolveu e você quiser, marca ele .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome dos campos do Json devem coincidir com os nomes das propriedades do objeto, é assim que o framework fazer a conversão automática.

No caso da pergunta o Json tem Resposta e o Controller espera Resp.

Como ele não localiza Resposta no Controller então ele ignora o campo do Json, e como ele não acha Resp no Json ele não carrega o valor Resp do Objeto.